# Convert positive data into negetive data (entire column) in Postgres Server

Tags: sql, postgresql

The current data in my table is:

> ```
>   a   b
> ---------  
>  -1   5
>  -11  2   
>  -5  32
> ```

My request is to convert every data of column a into negative value.

But how to update the positive values into the negative selecting the entire column?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Update table set a= 0-a where a >0
```

Comment: Based on this: "But how to update the positive values into the negative selecting the entire column?" Isn't your answer incorrect since it will make the negative values positive?

Comment: You can simply use `set a = -a` no need for the `0` thing there

Answer (score 8):

`UPDATE mytable SET a = a * -1;`

This multiplies all values in 'a' by -1. Now, if the value is already negative, it will become positive. You you want to make sure they are *always* negative, do this:

`UPDATE mytable SET a = a * -1 WHERE a > 0;`

Comment: No need for a multiplication, `set a = -a` will do just fine

Answer (score 0):

Just as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in his comments, the straightforward solution would be:

To negate all the existing values:

```
UPDATE mytable SET a = -a;
```

And if u want to make sure all values are negative:

```
UPDATE mytable SET a = -a where a > 0;
```